# BS4 find item by class

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

Im trying to make a simple web scraper
i have a htm file similar to this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <title>some text</title>
    <div class="ui-box-title">Item specifics</div>
     <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul> 
    <div class="description">Item specifics</div>
      <li>not interesting</li>
      <li>not interesting</li>
      <li>not interesting</li>
    ...
```

how to i extract just coffe tea and milk? i tryed this

```
    allaftuibox=soup.find_all_next("div", { "class" : "ui-box-title" }):
    allaftuibox.find_all("ul")
```

but allaftuibox is empty. where do i make the error? how do i extract just the ul? 
can someone help me?

Comment: Your approach actually looks good. Are you sure `soup` contains this list?

Comment: yes. just wrote the soup to a file. its there. is it possible that the real html is broken somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was surprisingly simple. 
I have managed to extract the middle part doing this:

```
for every in soup.findAll("div"):
            if "Product Description" in every:
                itsp=True
            if itsp:
                #print every
                #print every.find('img', {'class': 'sizedProdImage'})
                #desc.append(every)
                acv=0
            if "Packaging Details" in every:
                itsp=False
```

I'm not sure if this is the most elegand or most efficient solution but it works. 
And the second error was the find all with the class. this wont work at all in aliexpress for some reason i dont understand. The solution was to search for the text.

```
ntdesc=soup.find("span",text="Unlock Phones:").find_all_next()
```